# Why is this SVG ellipse not a gradient?

Tags: svg

The following SVG should show an ellipse that has a gradient from blue to green. But it's all green. Why?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:jfreesvg="http://www.jfree.org/jfreesvg/svg" width="2.0in" height="2.0in" text-rendering="auto" shape-rendering="auto" viewBox="0 0 1828800 1828800">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="783907957477109gp0" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="152400" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgb(0,0,255)"/>
   <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgb(0,255,0)"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <ellipse cx="228600" cy="304800" rx="76200" ry="152400" style="fill: url(#783907957477109gp0); fill-opacity: 1.0" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The gradient runs from 0 to 152400 in the y direction, anything bigger than y=152400 will be drawn in the last stop colour.
- The ellipse y centre is 304800 so its lowest point is 304800 - 152400 = 152400 which is the gradient end point.

Comment: thank you. And out of curiosity, whay isn't the gradient run with 0,0 at the one end of the ellipse?

Comment: Because the ellipse does not exist at 0. The co-ordinate system for userSpaceOnUse is the same for the gradient and the shape.